# In XCode 4.6 how do you create a brand new iOS application combining a tabbed main application with a navigation controller on one of the tabs?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.6

I am trying to add a navigation controller inside a tab bar controller in a brand new non-storyboard (plain old nib) style.

I found this [demo](http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/) which assumes that XCode has a new project template called "Tab Bar Application". It doesn't. Now XCode 4.6 has "New Tabbed Application".  Of course, Apple in their great wisdom has decided that I should not have a main window nib (.xib) and should have the tab bar controller and its pages coded for me in the app delegate instead of in a new-user-friendly NIB instantiated tab controller.  I guess that's because it's more flexible that way, and you can write code to decide what tabs the user sees and what tabs they don't see.  If I turn on Storyboards, then I guess I can do everything visually still.

I am deeply confused by the long and tortured history of XCode version differences, which affect the validity of existing questions on stackoverflow and demos elsewhere on the web, that reference different iOS versions, and different XCode versions, and make assumptions specific to versions of XCode and iOS that now appear to have changed, and which each rely on different choices with respect to the contents of your `Main Nib File Base Name` being set or not set.

I also find that it seems that pre-storyboard-Nibs and the complexities of combining various UIKit widgets and controllers has been a primary motivation behind the creation of storyboards.

I am working in a real non-storyboard nib-based application that appears to have been created before this change of heart at apple, and I can see that at startup a lot of unecessary views are created automatically by nib-instantiation and then deleted, in order to dynamically hide and show tabs on the tab bar controller.  This appears to have been thought about a great deal at Apple, and they've changed the recommended practices implicitly by changing the way new applications are generated in XCode.  I'm not questioning their wisdom, in fact I appreciate the change, but it's left me lost and confused.

Anyways, I'm just trying to put a navigation controller inside a tab in the main tab bar, and I already have an application that must have been started back when XCode used to generate a main window and generate a "Tab Bar Application" with a top level view that is a tabbed view, and the tab bar controller is nib instantiated. The demo above assumes as much.

Apple apparently famously never has provided a demo of this obvious combination of tab bar plus navigation controller. Or so I'm told.  And the Apple Human Interface Guidelines apparently state (or used to state?) that it's better to put a navigation controller inside a tab bar than vice versa, and my question should be understood as wishing to comply with the HIG however possible, so I believe I'm asking about the recommended combination, not the discouraged combination.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Tried to follow [this blog post](http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/), from circa 2009, which assumes things true about older versions of XCode that are no longer true.
2. Starting with a new tabbed application which XCode generated for me, **with storyboards turned OFF**, I have a root app delegate .m file that it generated for me that apparently creates at app-startup time, a Tab Bar Controller object completely in code, and which has no Main Window nib. The following code is entirely written by Apple, and I am wondering where (as a relatively new Cocoa developer) I'm supposed to break into this and place my new stuff, if I wanted to change one of the tabs to hav a nav bar and its associated UINavigationViewController:

-- This marker helps stackoverflow's busted markdown system not be confused --

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[RPDAFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RPDAFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[RPDASecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RPDASecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[RPDAFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RPDAFirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[RPDASecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RPDASecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It now appears that what used to be possible without writing code (according to that 2009 example on the blog I linked to) is now done purely in code.   I have read about 500 pages of "Programming iOS 5", worked for a few hundred hours on my first app, and tried a lot of demo applications but I'm still a relatively unseasoned Cocoa/iOS developer, and I believe part of my confusion over all this is the "controller and view" pattern, and its rules for combining them, both in code, and in nibs, are not entirely clear to me.

--

**Update**: You can has teh codez! [In the interest of helping out future XCode-cocoa-iOS noobs like me, I have made a complete demo app and posted it on github here.](https://github.com/wpostma/TabBarPlusNavPlay)

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I found also this demo, which is storyboard based. I'm looking for a non-storyboard approach because my existing app that I eventually need to add this to, has no storyboards, and I don't yet want to deal with storyboards.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ab5jyXihwRM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was as confused as you were when I did the same thing, but once you understand the structure you will find out that it is quite simple.

Basically, You want to create a UINavigationController with the RootViewController you want to display first:

```
[UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theViewControllerYouWantToDisplayFirst];
```

Then just add this controller to the array for your tab buttons.

```
NSArray *tabs = [[NSArray alloc] 
                        initWithObjects: navController, otherTab, etc];
```

Then, set your tabs using such array.

```
UITabBarController *rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[rootController setViewControllers:tabs];
```

and add it to your tab controller to your window:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:rootController];
```

And that is it. I took me some time to realize the way things are structured. The Tab View controller just holds a bunch of ViewControllers, you just need to make one of those view controllers your NavigationController.

Comment: This works.  However the resulting app has no image showing in the tab, even though I did set up one in `theViewControllerYouWantToDisplayFirst`.  Or am I supposed to really subclass UINavigationController, or otherwise set UINavigationController's OWN title or image?

Comment: No, you don't have too. This is how I set it up on my init method:   

[self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabIcon"]];

Comment: I think I did it right. If you don't mind having a quick look at the demo I posted, it might be helpful to future legions of iPhone noobs like me.

Comment: I looked at it and it looks good to me. I would remove: navController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigate"]; // this however, works. from the appDelegate, since, I think, It is to the ViewController to specify what it's title should be, not the delegate. I would appreciate a "corrected answer" if you think this is it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're saying take the image out?  Or the bit of code where i'm pointing out that the title (string) is not used even if it's set. If I take that image out, then the image is not properly set.

Comment: Just sent you a pull request with comments.

Comment: I merged it, and then did a longer comment so readers should understand the intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind starting a new app to get the basics going, try this:

Create a Tabbed Application (or whatever it's called nowadays):

Then select the view you want to have embedded in a NavigationController.

Then go to Editor -> Embed -> in NavigationController like shown below:

[image]

Your result will look like this:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: This is a great storyboard based answer. I'd prefer not to use storyboards, but other people on StackOverflow might want exactly this. Please don't rewrite it, because it may be that storyboards are the future and the SO community would prefer this answer. +1

Comment: I prefer not to use them unless I want to do something fancy with the UI. Especially putting an UITableView in an UIView and adding buttons, images and whatnot.

Comment: My feeling is that an app that has 10 non-storyboard views doesn't gain much from me adding one view that is storyboard based.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the first two answers (both correct), I add another method to come back to the original "Tabbed Application" template (maybe version 3 of XCode? I don't remember).
In this template you'll have a main xib file with, inside, your TabBarController.

You must start from the Empty Application template, then go through this steps:

- Add a new file, User Interface, Application Xib. In this tutorial I'll assume you will name it "Application.xib"
- Go to your AppDelegate.h file and change this line:

  @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

adding IBOutlet:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

- Go inside AppDelegate.m and change your applicationDidFinishLaunching method with this

:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // delete all and leave only the return
    return YES;
}
```

- Go inside Application.xib, select "App Delegate" from the Objects Menu, and then in the identity inspector change the Class --> write AppDelegate (or your AppDelegate.h class name)
- Always in Application.xib, right click again on App Delegate Object, you will see a "window" Outlet --> link it to the Window object in the Object inspector on the left
- Now, come back to the project, go in supporting files, main.m and change the return line like this:

:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

- then, go inside the main .plist file and add a key: right click, add, key, "Main Nib File Base Name", Type String, Value "Application" (without quotes, without .xib extension)

Ok, now you have an empty "old style" nib application. Now you can go again inside Application.xib, drag your TabBar and link it as the Window "root view controller" (right click on the Window, link the root view controller property).
Then, inside the tab bar, you can drag ViewControllers, Navigation controllers, ecc...

If you need other details or images write me

EDIT:

I uploaded a sample project if you want to look: http://www.lombax.it/documents/ManualTab.zip

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I would +1 you twice if I could. The demo is very good because it's easier to grasp a sample of working code and take it apart than to make the intuitive leap from a description of something to being able to write it. (On the other hand, it's the intuitive leaps from words to code that show you really understand a subject matter, and that is where I find I'm still early on in the learning curve.)

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot because I think it will help out people who need to see what we're talking about to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a working application that I wanted to place under one "leg" of a tabbed application. I wanted to develop other portions of the "bigger app" under the other tabs. I didn't want to use storyboards. That removed a good deal of the solutions I found. Most of the remaining solutions were developed using older versions of Xcode and they simply wouldn't work with the version of Xcode I downloaded in Feb of 2013.

I tried creating my own tabbed application - (starting with an "Empty Application") as some of the developers on this thread had used. I felt like I was getting close, but I simply couldn't get it to work.

There is an excellent tutorial on using a "Tabbed Application with a Navigation Controller" by Vishal Kurup.

With a minor modification (listed below) by following the video I was able to slip my existing application under the default "Tabbed Application" created by Xcode.

Create a TabBar Controller with a Navigation Controller + Detail View in Xcode 4.3

can be found at

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMpNbCs4mr4

the only real change I had to make from the default "Tabbed Application" was in the AppDelegate.m:

the following code supplied by the selecting "Tabbed Application" wouldn't serve my purpose

```
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
```

this did

```
 self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigation ,
     viewController1 ,viewController2, viewController3, viewController4,  nil];
```

A big thank you goes out to Mr Vishal Kurup.
He has made a number of quality videos on iOS development.